# Do we always use "more" to compare two things?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality-in-context

Do we always use "more" to compare two things?

> Among the various and conflicting interpretations of Aristophanes’
>   works, there is a general admiration for the
>   poet’s seemingly boundless imaginative power and his
>   habit of allowing the creative human spirit to triumph over
>   all constraints of reality. Critics and scholars across the
>   centuries have equated Aristophanes with the best of the
>   Old Comedy, ignoring other representatives of this particular
>   art, such as Cratinus or Eupolis, partly because only
>   Aristophanes’ comedies have survived in complete form.
>   Aristophanes’ fame eventually waned after his death,
>   but he quickly became central to the Western literary
>   canon. Among the early authors who wrote commentaries
>   on Aristophanes were Photius, the erudite patriarch
>   of Constantinople, and John Tzetzes, the noted encyclopedist.
>   Plato’s attitude toward the comic poet was **more
>   ambivalent**, but this was probably because of Aristophanes’
>   devastating portrayal of Socrates in The Clouds.
>
> <sup>Source: GALE CONTEXTUAL ENCYCLOPEDIA OF WORLD LITERATURE</sup>

Does this context compare Plato with other people who criticize Aristophans? 
Or does "more" here just come to emphasis and means *very*?

Which paraphrase is better?

- 1: Plato’s attitude toward the comic poet was more
  ambivalent than other.

or

- 2: Plato’s attitude toward the comic poet was very
  ambivalent.
  ??

Source: GALE CONTEXTUAL ENCYCLOPEDIA OF WORLD LITERATURE

Answer (score 5):

Offhand I can't think of any contexts where ***more*** doesn't carry strong (but perhaps *implicit* rather than *explicit*) connotations of "comparison" (with something / someone else that's ***less***).

Unquestionably, the cited example states how ambivalent *Plato* was ***by comparison*** with  Photius and John Tzetzes. But all it says is Plato was ***more*** ambivalent than them - he might still not be ***very*** ambivalent (by comparison with others).

---

***But*** it's worth pointing out that although I think the comparative form ***more*** always carries the "literal" sense of *to a greater degree **than** something else*, this isn't the case with the superlative form ***most***. For example,...

> 1: *Thank you! You've been most kind*
>    2: *When I lost my job, the bank manager was most helpful*
>    3: *Your son is a most promising pupil*

In all those cases, it makes more sense to understand ***most*** as meaning ***very***, with no particular allusion to "more than any other".

---

EDIT:
Taking account of points raised in comments, I'd say that *in and of itself*, ***more*** carries no particular implications of ***very*** - it's purely a "relative comparative". As I understand it, I can truthfully say *Light travels more slowly through water than through air*. But that certainly doesn't imply light travels ***very*** slowly through water!

Comment: I think it's only by implication that Plato's attitude toward Aristophanes was more ambivalent than those of Photius and Tzetzes. It's more about characterizing his (Plato's) commentary as more ambivalent, as opposed to unequivocally in favor of Aristophanes.

Comment: I have no idea whether Photius and / or John Tzetzes were "unequivocally in favor" of Aristophanes - but to me the cited text itself doesn't particularly imply that. So far as I'm concerned, all it does is assert that ***relatively speaking*** Plato was more ambivalent than them. And your interpretation would completely vanish if we were to include just one extra word, that doesn't really affect ***my*** reading *(Plato’s attitude ... was **even** more ambivalent)*.

Comment: (Oh - not necessarily totally relevant, but [***here's the evidence***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/33405/2637) that I myself am unequivocally in favor of Aristophanes! :)

Comment: I didn't say Photius and / or Tzetzes were unequivocally in favor of Aristophanes. I said Plato was more ambivalent than those that were unequivocally in favor of him; those commentators that are described as possessing "a general admiration for the poet’s seemingly boundless imaginative power", and who have "equated Aristophanes with the best of the Old Comedy". What I'm saying is that Plato's commentary was more ambivalent than those. The text mentions Photius and Tzetzes, but it's not specifically them (rather, only by implication) that Plato's commentary is contrasted against.

Comment: If by that you mean you think OP's cited text ***isn't*** explicitly comparing how ambivalent Plato was ***specifically by comparison with Photius and Tzetzes***, all I can say is I disagree. In *other* contexts, it's possible ***more*** could be used "generically" (without specific reference to particular things/people which are  "less") - but per the first sentence in my answer, I can't think of any clear-cut examples of that.

Comment: I do not understand how "more" gets confused with "very." The quoted text does imply that Photius and Tzetzes were neither entirely positive nor entirely negative in their evaluations of Aristophanes, but there is no warrant in the text to conclude that Plato grossly differed from that assessment.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow: But that's the main ***point*** of my answer! OP asked *does "**more**" here just come to emphasis and means "**very**"?* To which the answer is ***No**, "**more**" never does - but in certain contexts as specified, "**most**" can indeed mean "**very**"*. And maybe I haven't combed through OP's cited text carefully enough, but I don't see any particular implication that Photius and Tzetzes were significantly more ***or*** less ambivalent about Aristophanes than whatever we might call an "average" reaction. All we really know is that Plato was more ambivalent than they were.

Comment: @FF I was not disagreeing with your answer. I do not think you made it as clear as possible that "more" does not **entail** "very." Your "might not be very" is correct, but leaves open the possibility that "more" usually implies "very." An OP who is confused about "more" and "very" will benefit from a simple and correct statement. "More" does not entail "very." As for the passage itself, "more ambivalent" certainly implies that those named were ambivalent to some degree. I said nothing more than that.

Comment: oic. Yes, I recall that when I was writing my first sentence, I deliberately "weakened" my assertion. And I continued hedging right up to the *last* sentence of my "Specific Answer" section *(**more** ambivalent ... **might** not be **very** ambivalent).* I knew I was going to go on to explain about how OP might reasonably have been misled by the idiomatic use of ***most = very*** as set out in the "Related" section, but although I wanted to assert ...BUT ***more*** DOESN'T! I was thinking "Maybe it sometimes does; I just can't come up with an example". But no-one else has (yet! :)